# F# application can't find any of of my imports

Tags: .net, linux, ubuntu, f#, f#-giraffe

I'm trying to get started in writing some f# giraffe applications, on my ubuntu machine .I'm currently following [this guide](https://www.softwarepark.cc/blog/2020/7/13/introduction-to-web-programming-in-f-with-giraffe-part-1).

I have dotnet installed:

```
ask@Garsy:~/Downloads/giraffe$ dotnet --versionask@Garsy:~/Downloads/giraffe$ dotnet --version
```

5.0.203
5.0.203

I'vebeen following these setup steps from the guide:

```
dotnet new console -lang F#
dotnet add package Giraffe
dotnet add package Giraffe.ViewEngine
```

Which has all worked great. I run my program using `dotnet run` which works fine, the issue happens when i have to actually import stuff All these imports:

```
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
open Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
open Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
open Giraffe.GiraffeViewEngine
open FSharp.Control.Tasks.V2.ContextInsensitive
```

I'm using vs code, and they light up as red as well. I'm pretty confused about how to get these dependencies, I thought that I should have the giraffe ones from the commands I ran.

Is there some kind of Nuget package manager for linux, that I can use?

UPDATE:

I've been trying to use `dotnet add package <PACKAGE_NAME>` to install pakcages. But running:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore
```

Has not effect, theses three imports still have red lines below them, and still show up when running:

```
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
```

*EDIT*

I now pressed "debug default project" as supplied by the f# plugin, and now the red lines are gone and, it seems like f# is able to find my dependencies.
However, I am now getting this when I run the project, and I have no idea what it could be caused by:

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.203/NuGet.targets(1056,5): error MSB4006: There is a circular dependency in the target dependency graph involving target "_GenerateRestoreProjectPathWalk". [/home/ask/Git/Giraffe/Giraffe.fsproj]
Unable to create dependency graph file for project '/home/ask/Git/Giraffe/Giraffe.fsproj'. Cannot add package reference.
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'It has no effect'? Do you see any information returned by the command?

Comment: The actual command produced an output that told me that the package was being downloaded . But the program was still not working. There has been a development, will update

Comment: I think your project file doesn't have the web SDK attribute in it. There is no such thing as adding the ASP.NET packages. They are a "framework reference". Use `Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"` in the `.fsproj` file. It's strange that the guide doesn't describe this, as it's fundamental to web projects with .NET.